# SysML parser for python

Tags: python, parsing, uml, sysml

Does anyone know any good SysML parser libraries in Python?

I'm already using the ***org.eclipse.uml2.uml*** library in ***Java*** but I couldn't find the equivalent in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gaphor](https://gaphor.org) is a simple SysML modeling tool written in Python. It includes a SysML parser built-in that it uses to generate a Python data model from a gaphor model of the SysML specification. The Python module is called [codegen](https://github.com/gaphor/gaphor/blob/master/gaphor/codegen/codegen.py).

To use it you would create a SysML model using Gaphor. Then you would run the codegen like:

```
python codegen.py modelfile outfile overrides
```

The overrides file can be used to override the generation of Python to customize to your needs.

I'm not sure what your exact use case is from your question, but I think this would at least along the lines of what you are looking for.